# Quotient space from the 8-sided polygonal region of the labelling scheme $abcdad^{-1}cb^{-1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is Exercise 4 of §75 of Munkres' *Topology*.

It is interesting because unlike the previous exercises, not all the vertices of the polygon are mapped to the same point. So one cannot mechanically apply existing theorems. Below is the exercise.

Let $X$ be the quotient space obtained from an 8-sided polygonal region $P$ by means of the labelling scheme $abcdad^{-1}cb^{-1}$. Let $\pi: P \rightarrow X$ be the quotient map.

1. Show that $\pi$ does not map all the vertices of $P$ to the same point of $X$.
2. Determine the space $A = \pi(\text{Bd} P)$ and calculate its fundamental group.
3. Calculate $\pi_1 (X, x_0)$ and $H_1(X)$.
4. Assuming $X$ is homeomorphic to one of the surfaces given in Theorem 75.5, which surface is it?

Answer (score 0):

If we draw the polygon, it is easy to see that its border corresponds to graph $P$ made of three circles as below.

[image]

If we pick the intersection of the two left-most circles as $x_0$, $\pi_1(P,x_0)$ is the free product of $\{a, bd, bcb^{-1}\}$. Let $\alpha = bd$ and $\beta = bcb^{-1}$. We have $abcdad^{-1}cb^{-1} = a \beta\alpha a \alpha^{-1} \beta$.

Thus $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is the same as the quotient space obtained from a 6-sided polygonal region $P$ by means of the labelling scheme $a \beta\alpha a \alpha^{-1} \beta$. Unlike the original problem, this one has all its vertices mapped to the same point.

Applying the standard technique, we see that $H_1(X)$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ by $0 \times 0 \times 2\mathbb{Z}$. $X$ is thus homeomorphic to the 3-fold connected sum of projective planes.